# Apply css background red to after second li onwards jquery

Tags: jquery, html

There are number of li dynamically appended i want apply css backround after 2nd li

```
<ul>

 <li>hello </li>
 <li>hello </li>
 <li>hello </li>
 <li>hello </li>
 <li>hello </li>

</ul>


   $("ul li").after(3).css("background" , "red");
```

but it is not working . Any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
ul li:nth-child(n + 3){
    background: red;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kXZ39/)

or using jQuery

```
$("ul li").slice(2).css("background" , "red");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L2QE9/)

Comment: Arun - your css answer is good but  i am asked jquery only now i got another question use gt is best or slice is best

Comment: @sudhar slice is better, from [:gt-doc](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) - `Because :gt() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :gt() cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use $("your-pure-css-selector").slice(index) instead.`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [:gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h85CW/)**

```
 $("ul li:gt(2)").css("background" , "red");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `:gt(2)`

```
$("ul li:gt(2)").css("background" , "red");
```

`---->`  https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to add another class to that dynamically created li-s and apply `background: red` css to that class. So, any dynamically created li-s will have the background red css. You don't have to give a number there.